# Using jQuery Datatables, how do I input values from JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I'm pretty new to working on JS based web apps so here is my question. I've got a datatable setup and it is functioning correctly with hardcoded data, and I'm getting my JSON result. What I don't know how is how to use the JSON results to populate the table and replace the hardcoded data.

Below is where I've got to with the JS, so I'm looking to dynamically load in the content for `".1"-".5"`

```
function fnClickAddRow() {

$.getJSON('thelink',function(data){
    var dealers = data['dealers'];

    $.each(dealers,function(x,dealer){

    $('#example').addClass( "table datatable table-striped table-bordered sub-table" );
    $('#example').removeClass( "dataTable" );

    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    '<img id="' + dealer['user_id'] + '" src="assets/utopia/icons/add.png">',
    dealer['name'],
    ".1",
    ".2",
    ".3",
    ".4",
    ".5",
    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="edit_user(27186);" class="edit"><img alt="Edit user" src="/assets/utopia/icons/pencil.png" title="Edit User"></a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove_user_confirm(27186);" class="delete"><img alt="Remove user" src="/assets/utopia/icons/trash_can.png" title="Remove User"></a>'] );

    });
});
```

Comment: the mixing hardoced and dynamic data have some problem in datatables, see my [issue](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/145) and [patch](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/pull/146)

Comment: also datatables have own ajax api, [check here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just show only json data in datatables, check documentation:
http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/server-data-formats

If you need replace dynamically (add/delete) rows in table, look at this:
http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html
and check fnDeleteRow method:
http://www.datatables.net/api